# Smarty expected "}"

Tags: php, smarty

I'm using smarty and php for a site and i have no idea why would i get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "C:\wamp\www\radacina\template\index\index.tpl" on line 23 "$(['images/bg-red.jpg','images/bg-orange.jpg','images/bg-green.jpg']).bgSlider({bgstretch:false,current:0,pags:'.pagination li a'})" - Unexpected ":", expected one of: "}" , " " , ATTR' in C:\wamp\www\radacina\include\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 656

Line 23 is exactly the one described in the error in case you might ask .

Comment: The error seems very straight. That line of code has errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smarty thinks that the given line is a smarty template expression, but it looks like some javascript.
You should add a `{literal}` before the line, and a `{/literal}` after the line to let smarty know that this line should not be parsed.

(Or you can use newer smarty versions or override the the default delimiters.)

And the related docs: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal